# How do I make an enum of arrays in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have an object with fixed keys that I use as an enum-like object. The values are variable length arrays. This works as desired. However it requires duplicating the same type assertion on every value in the object. Is there a way to type them all at once instead of individually?

```
const Direction = 'u' | 'r' | 'd' | 'l'

const gestures = {
  newSubThought: ['r', 'd', 'r'] as Direction[],
  newThought: ['r', 'd'] as Direction[],
  clearThought: ['l', 'r'] as Direction[],
  ...
}
```

If I omit `as Direction[]` then the values are too wide, not allowing me to pass `gestures.newThought` as a `Direction[]`.

```
The type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Direction'.
```

If I widen the keys to `{ [key: string]: Direction[] }` then I lose the narrow keys and the autocompletion that comes with it.

Comment: "then it is too narrow" should probably be "then it is too *wide*", since `string` is wider than `Direction`, and `string[]` is wider than `Direction[]` (you can assign a `Direction[]` value to a variable of type `string[]` but not vice versa)

Comment: You're right, I must have been thinking of a version with `as const` which creates narrow values. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#25214](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25214) requesting the ability to annotate the type of the *values* of an object, while allowing the compiler to somehow infer the *keys*.  For now there is no direct support for this; and the issue is marked as "needs proposal", meaning that it's not clear how such a feature would work.  If you're really interested in seeing this happen, you could give that issue a  and possibly suggest how it would work.

For now, though, you can get indirect support for this via a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) identity helper function:

```
const asGestures = <K extends PropertyKey>(
    gestures: { [P in K]: Direction[] }) => gestures;
```

Instead of annotating or [asserting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that each property of your object literal  is a `Direction[]`, you call `asGestures()` on the "plain" object literal.  The compiler will constrain the type of the object to something whose values are of type `Direction[]`, and whose keys are of type a key-like type `K` it infers:

```
const gestures = asGestures({
    newSubThought: ['r', 'd', 'r'],
    newThought: ['r', 'd'],
    clearThought: ['l', 'r']
    //...
})
/* const gestures: {
    newSubThought: Direction[];
    newThought: Direction[];
    clearThought: Direction[];
} */
```

Even better, if you make a mistake in your array, the compiler will notice and catch it for you:

```
const badGestures = asGestures({
    begoneThought: ['r', 'u', 'd', 'e'], // error!
    // --------------------------> ~~~
    // Type '"e"' is not assignable to type 'Direction'.
})
```

whereas type assertions using `as` will tend to suppress such errors (one major use of type assertions is to narrow types past what the compiler can verify):

```
['r', 'u', 'd', 'e'] as Direction[] // no error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgJwgY2HA9gOygXigcgFd8oAfAhE8-AEyoIBt8BuAKFeSwGdgoBDLgHEIPQki64oAHgDSUCAA9gETDQkAFBOkgJQMiCAB8AClZRzUAOYjgYkQC4oAbygBtdVDjYZAXUfwkVAxMVx8oAF8ASlxDKxs7LjYObl5rUXFJAWF0kWMnMwtMCAB3AGVCACMAFQALdEJLGuBHV3xKABoCOk62-B92gvMi4tr6xua3Xp66fsGoZAYIPgRRhqaW-CYeyh85gHo9gDpj1ijWPYAqeZS4nK5HfIsoYfLqurWJgJQ0LFC2J+Gq3G-kQ32CfzmCyWK3ewNgoKCvx8bHCUAue3YnEwPCgFT4NGytgyeCy8XEeTmFQgliwECB60mHQIxGm+B6ED6nQO8gQWgQAEJ9nsoABaMXiiWSqWS2IAP3lQqgVXA0HwACIIGqSHAJJh0LwBFw4JZMHwKosoMB0JaVQQvojMPhDqdIklWkyiGyul78BywgJ4YEfiFkVBuXqeXz2L6SAH7cG2EA)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could find was using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
// define an enum-like object with the exact values
// (optionally add `as const` for readonly keys)
const gestureEnum = {
  newSubThought: ['r', 'd', 'r'],
  newThought: ['r', 'd'],
  clearThought: ['l', 'r'],
  ...
}

// widen the type of the gestureEnum values to Direction[] using a mapped type
export const gestures = gestureEnum as {
  [key in keyof typeof gestureEnum]: Direction[]
}

/* The final type:

const gestures: {
  newSubThought: Direction[],
  newThought: Direction[],
  clearThought: Direction[],
  ...
}

*/
```